# What's wrong with my Html 5 Javascript Canvas Game code? I'm a beginner

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm a beginner. I tried to copy code on to Notepad++ and run it on Chrome. It failed to run (not show anything). Please help. I don't know what's wrong with it.

My code below is a basic game missile roket boss. I was tying to make a game for the first time following a book tutorial. But my first game couldn't even run anything. Nothing was drawn on the canvas. Would it be the src of the image? I'm using Windows10. Could it be the OS or the antivirus? I'm using McAfee.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Game Loop</title></head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var fps=50;  //specify framerate per second
 var timing=0;
 var ctxP=document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
 var imgBg1 = new Image();
 var imgBg2 = new Image();
 var imgBg3 = new Image();
 var imgRocket = new Image();
 var imgBoss = new Image();
 
 // Enemy 1 and 2
 var imgEnemy = new Image();
 var enemyPos1 = {x:Math.random()*320,y:0};
 var enemyPos2 = {x:Math.random()*320,y:-100};
 var enemy1 = new drawEnemy(0.01,1,enemyPos1.x,enemyPos1.y,50,50);
 var enemy2 = new drawEnemy(0.05,2,enemyPos2.x,enemyPos2.y,50,50);
 var keyframeObject=2;
 var count=0;
 var delay=10;
 var posBossX=170;
 var rocketPos = {x:220,y:220};
 var keyframeRocket=1;
  setInerval{Update,1000/fps}; //function to call for Update function 
 var imgMissile = new Image(); //Create Missile Variable
 var missilePos={enable:false,keyframeObject:1,x:0,y:0};
 //Variable to draw missle 
 //keyframe 1 and initial at (0,0)
 function Update(){
  window.addEventListener('click',clickReporter,false);
  //Call function clickReporter when the mouse is clicked
  document.addEventListener('keydown',checkKeyDown,false);
  //Call function clickReporter when the key is down
  document.addEventListener('keyup',checkKeyUp,false);
  //Call function clickReporter when the key is up
  timing+=0.2;
  drawBg(timing);
  drawRocket(keyframeRocket,rocketPos.x,rocketPos.y);
           //call for function to draw Rocket1
  drawBoss(posBossX,0);
  enemyPos1.y++;
  enemy1.setY(enemyPos1.y);
  enemy1.draw();
  enemyPos2.y++;
  enemy2.setY(enemyPos2.y);
  enemy2.draw();
  
//write  function here
function drawBg(timing){
 imgBg1.src='images/bg1.png'; //to load bg
 imgBg2.src='images/bg2.png';
 imgBg3.src='images/bg3.png';
 ctxP.drawImage(imgBg1,0,320-timing/2,480,320,0,0,480,320);
 ctxP.drawImage(imgBg2,0,320-timing,480,320,0,0,480,320);
 ctxP.drawImage(imgBg3,0,320-timing*1.5,480,320,0,0,480,320);
}
function drawRocket(keyframe,posX,posY){
 imgRocket.src='images/rocket.png';  //to load rocket.png
 ctxP.drawImage(imgRocket,((keyframe-1)*100),0,100,100,posX,posY,50,50);
}
function drawBoss(posX,posY){
 imgBoss.src='images/boss.png';  //to load boss.png
 ctxP.drawImage(imgBoss,posX,posY);
}
function drawEnemy1(keyframe,row,posX,posY){
 imgEnemy1.src='images/enemy.png';
 ctxP.drawImage(imgEnemy1,((keyframe-1)*50),((row-1)*50),50,50,posX,posY,50,50);
}
function drawEnemy2(keyframe,row,posX,posY){
 imgEnemy2.src='images/enemy.png';
 ctxP.drawImage(imgEnemy2,((keyframe-1)*50),((row-1)*50),50,50,posX,posY,50,50);
}
function drawEnemy(delay,row,posX,posY,desWidth,desHeight){
 this.delay=delay;
 this.count=0;
 this.enable=true;
 this.keyframe=1;
 this.row=row;
 this.posX=posX;
 this.posY=posY;
 this.desWidth=desWidth;
 this.desHeight=desHeight;
 drawEnemy.prototype.setX=function(posX){
  this.posX=posX;
  }
 drawEnemy.prototype.setY=function(posY){
  this.posY=posY;
  }
 drawEnemy.prototype.enable=function(enable){
  this.enable=enable;
  }
 drawEnemy.prototype.draw=function(){
  this.count+=this.delay;
  if(this.count>=1){
   if(this.keyframe==1){
   this.keyframe=2;
   }else{
   this.keyframe=1;
  }
   if(this.count>=1){this.count=0;}
  }
  imgEnemy.src = 'images/enemy.png';
  ctwP.drawImage(imgEnemy.(this.keyframe-1)*50,(this.row-1)*50,50,50,
  this.posX,this.posY,this.desWidth,this.desHeight);
 }
}
function checkKeyDown(e){
 var key = e.keyCode;
 if(key == 87){ 
 rocketPos.y=rocketPos.y-5;
 }//if press w reduce y by 5
 if(key=83){ 
  rocketPos.y=rocketPos.y+5;
 }//if press s add y by 5
 if(key==65){ 
  rocketPos.x=rocketPos.x-5;
 }//if press A reduce x by 5
 if(key=68){ 
  rocketPos.x=rocketPos.x+5;
 }//if press D add x by 5
 if(key=88){ 
  missilePos.enable=true; //if press X, status is enable, true
  missilePos.x=rocketPos.x;//origin point Missile at rocket
  missilePos.y=rocketPos.y;
 }
}
function checkKeyUp(e){
 var key = e.keyCode;
 //alert(key);
 if(key==65){
  keyframeRocket=1;//make keyframe 1 (front) when release A
 }
 if(key==68){
  keyframeRocket=1; //make keyframe 1 (front) when release D
 }
}
function drawMissile(keyframe.posX,posY){
 imgMissile.src= 'images/missile.png'; //load missle.png
 ctxP.drawImage(imgMissile,{(keyframe-1)*25},0,25,25,posX,posY,25,25); // Missile.png has two keyframes and size by 25
}
function clickReporter(e){
 positionX=e.pageX; // possitionX for cursor position on X
 possisiontY=e.pageY;  // possitionY for cursor position on Y
 alert("X="+possitionX+",Y="+positionY);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any error in the console?

Comment: `imgBg1.src='images/bg1.png';` etc are going to fail if you don't actually have any image files. The console should show you _exactly_ what's wrong. (try hitting **F12** to open it, then refresh the page to see the output)

Comment: Thank you very much. I hit F12 several times to fix lines.

Comment: Oops hit Enter by accident. I fixed lines until I found it says 'setInterval is not defined.' I don't know what it is though.

Comment: Got it. I spelled 'setInterval' wrongfully. hufff..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a lot of syntax errors. I've fixed them all. Now you just have to create the folder named `images` and put all the images in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Game Loop</title></head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fps=50;     //specify framerate per second
    var timing=0;
    var ctxP=document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
    var imgBg1 = new Image();
    var imgBg2 = new Image();
    var imgBg3 = new Image();
    var imgRocket = new Image();
    var imgBoss = new Image();

    // Enemy 1 and 2
    var imgEnemy = new Image();
    var enemyPos1 = {x:Math.random()*320,y:0};
    var enemyPos2 = {x:Math.random()*320,y:-100};
    var enemy1 = new drawEnemy(0.01,1,enemyPos1.x,enemyPos1.y,50,50);
    var enemy2 = new drawEnemy(0.05,2,enemyPos2.x,enemyPos2.y,50,50);
    var keyframeObject=2;
    var count=0;
    var delay=10;
    var posBossX=170;
    var rocketPos = {x:220,y:220};
    var keyframeRocket=1;
        setInterval(Update,1000/fps); //function to call for Update function 
    var imgMissile = new Image(); //Create Missile Variable
    var missilePos={enable:false,keyframeObject:1,x:0,y:0};
    //Variable to draw missle 
    //keyframe 1 and initial at (0,0)
    function Update(){
        window.addEventListener('click',clickReporter,false);
        //Call function clickReporter when the mouse is clicked
        document.addEventListener('keydown',checkKeyDown,false);
        //Call function clickReporter when the key is down
        document.addEventListener('keyup',checkKeyUp,false);
        //Call function clickReporter when the key is up
        timing+=0.2;
        drawBg(timing);
        drawRocket(keyframeRocket,rocketPos.x,rocketPos.y);
                                            //call for function to draw Rocket1
        drawBoss(posBossX,0);
        enemyPos1.y++;
        enemy1.setY(enemyPos1.y);
        enemy1.draw();
        enemyPos2.y++;
        enemy2.setY(enemyPos2.y);
        enemy2.draw();
    }

//write  function here
function drawBg(timing){
    imgBg1.src='images/bg1.png'; //to load bg
    imgBg2.src='images/bg2.png';
    imgBg3.src='images/bg3.png';
    ctxP.drawImage(imgBg1,0,320-timing/2,480,320,0,0,480,320);
    ctxP.drawImage(imgBg2,0,320-timing,480,320,0,0,480,320);
    ctxP.drawImage(imgBg3,0,320-timing*1.5,480,320,0,0,480,320);
}
function drawRocket(keyframe,posX,posY){
    imgRocket.src='images/rocket.png';  //to load rocket.png
    ctxP.drawImage(imgRocket,((keyframe-1)*100),0,100,100,posX,posY,50,50);
}
function drawBoss(posX,posY){
    imgBoss.src='images/boss.png';  //to load boss.png
    ctxP.drawImage(imgBoss,posX,posY);
}
function drawEnemy1(keyframe,row,posX,posY){
    imgEnemy1.src='images/enemy.png';
    ctxP.drawImage(imgEnemy1,((keyframe-1)*50),((row-1)*50),50,50,posX,posY,50,50);
}
function drawEnemy2(keyframe,row,posX,posY){
    imgEnemy2.src='images/enemy.png';
    ctxP.drawImage(imgEnemy2,((keyframe-1)*50),((row-1)*50),50,50,posX,posY,50,50);
}
function drawEnemy(delay,row,posX,posY,desWidth,desHeight){
    this.delay=delay;
    this.count=0;
    this.enable=true;
    this.keyframe=1;
    this.row=row;
    this.posX=posX;
    this.posY=posY;
    this.desWidth=desWidth;
    this.desHeight=desHeight;
    drawEnemy.prototype.setX=function(posX){
        this.posX=posX;
        }
    drawEnemy.prototype.setY=function(posY){
        this.posY=posY;
        }
    drawEnemy.prototype.enable=function(enable){
        this.enable=enable;
        }
    drawEnemy.prototype.draw=function(){
        this.count+=this.delay;
        if(this.count>=1){
            if(this.keyframe==1){
            this.keyframe=2;
            }else{
            this.keyframe=1;
        }
            if(this.count>=1){this.count=0;}
        }
        imgEnemy.src = 'images/enemy.png';
        ctwP.drawImage(imgEnemy,(this.keyframe-1)*50,(this.row-1)*50,50,50,
        this.posX,this.posY,this.desWidth,this.desHeight);
    }
}
function checkKeyDown(e){
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if(key == 87){ 
    rocketPos.y=rocketPos.y-5;
    }//if press w reduce y by 5
    if(key=83){ 
        rocketPos.y=rocketPos.y+5;
    }//if press s add y by 5
    if(key==65){ 
        rocketPos.x=rocketPos.x-5;
    }//if press A reduce x by 5
    if(key=68){ 
        rocketPos.x=rocketPos.x+5;
    }//if press D add x by 5
    if(key=88){ 
        missilePos.enable=true; //if press X, status is enable, true
        missilePos.x=rocketPos.x;//origin point Missile at rocket
        missilePos.y=rocketPos.y;
    }
}
function checkKeyUp(e){
    var key = e.keyCode;
    //alert(key);
    if(key==65){
        keyframeRocket=1;//make keyframe 1 (front) when release A
    }
    if(key==68){
        keyframeRocket=1; //make keyframe 1 (front) when release D
    }
}
function drawMissile(keyframe,posX,posY){
    imgMissile.src= 'images/missile.png'; //load missle.png
    ctxP.drawImage(imgMissile,(keyframe-1)*25,0,25,25,posX,posY,25,25); // Missile.png has two keyframes and size by 25
}
function clickReporter(e){
    positionX=e.pageX; // possitionX for cursor position on X
    possisiontY=e.pageY;  // possitionY for cursor position on Y
    alert("X="+possitionX+",Y="+positionY);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you solving the problem.

Comment: Yes. Have a look at this very precise [Tour of stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)